# Display second <span> element in front of first

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a second sibling  element displaying in front of the first - with some severe restrictions:

I cannot alter the HTML or use javascript or jQuery.

I can only use CSS.

I can't change how classes are assigned (again, I don't have access to change any code apart from the one bespoke CSS file).

The left-hand menu features a number of the above HTML structures, building a clickable menu for the sections on the page. When a page section is completed, the 'completed-section' class is added to the first span (as shown above). This is what is causing me problems:

The CSS styling of the nav-link 'button' should change when it's completed, but since I can't access the parent of a CSS-selected element I need to make these changes directly to the 'menu-number' span element, including a 'nav-link' sized background colour. So I've made the menu-number  the same size as the containing 'nav-link' . But when I add a background colour to the 'menu-number' , the text in the second  is obscured.

**How can I 'move' the second span in front of the first so I can see its text?**

I have also tried making both spans position absolute or position relative and used z-index but this pulls the spans out of the flow of the document and means the width of the menu collapses. I can't set the width to a hard-coded value because the menu toggles open and closed, width-wise, (without a class being set) and the toggled width is set by javascript which, again, I can't access.

I have also tried using display: flex on the 'a' element and reversing the 'order' of span elements. No luck.

In semi-desperation I have tried setting the direction property on 'nav-link' to rtl. No luck.

I think I've tried a couple other things too, but at this point I'll wrap this question up.

Any pointers, much appreciated...

```css
.menu-number {
 border: none;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 0px;
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 height: 45px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 z-index: 100;
    float: left;
}
.menu-number + span {
 /*position: absolute;*/
 padding-left: 40px;
 z-index: 200;
}
.completed-section {
 color: #42bb76 !important;
 border-left: 10px solid #42bb76;
 background-color: #274d56;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.nav-link > div > a {
 display: flex;
 */flex-direction: row-reverse;*/
}
.nav-link > div > a > span:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 2;
}
.nav-link > div > a > span:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 1;
}
.nav-link > div > a > .section-name {
color: white;
padding: 13px 20px 0px 60px;
height: 45px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link">
    <div>
        <a href="scroll/to/section">
            <span class="menu-number completed-section">1.</span>
            <span class="section-name">Section name</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried 'flex-direction' but I've now commented that out.

Comment: is this the result you want? [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmgExP](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmgExP)

Comment: Hi can you post your CSS too ? or a jsFiddle would help !

Comment: Perhaps in css use "content : 'thecontent" on the pseudo-element "before" of the span ?

Comment: OK, it looks like it's working on the snippet above, but NOT on my version. There must be something I've not translated across to this pared-down example. Give me a minute to establish what it is and I'll make the correct changes to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `CSS` `order` property:

Here is the fiddle:

```css
.menu-number {
  order: 2;
}

.section-name {
  order: 1;
}

.nav-link a{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link">
  <div>
    <a href="scroll/to/section">
      <span class="menu-number completed-section">1.</span>
      <span class="section-name">Section name</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but on my version (which has .menu-number position set to absolute - see CSS added to question above) the text of the second span is still not visible. If I remove the position: absolute of the first span, the second span drops below the first. Also I'd like the section name to be displayed after the section number, but I'm betting some positioning could fix that.

Comment: @moosefetcher check yopur css properly there is class name mistakes for e.g .menunumber should be menu-number. and .navLink should be nav-link. check other mistakes as well and let me know

Comment: Sorry - I changed them in the HMTL here so as not to get 'have consistent convention!' complaints, but didn't change them in the CSS - will do that now. (I did not code the HTML or decide to use such non-consistent naming conventions, BTW!)

Comment: Even the snippet in my question is now working, but the problem persists in my live version, so there must be something about the full project that I've not translated to the example here. I'll try to figure out what that is and add it above,.

Comment: Yes..may be some other css causing the problem.

Comment: OK! display: flex was being overridden by another rule. Didn't spot that. This answer works, thanks.